# Script to generate password with uppercase lowercase number and symbol with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I use this script to generate password on zapier. It works well but I found it sometimes generates password without number. Can you give me live demo of it [here](https://js-demo.com)

```js
function generateP() {
  var pass = '';
  var str = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' + 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' + '1234567890' + '!@#$%^&()_+~`|}{[]:;?><,./-=';
  for (var i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
    var char = Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length + 1);
    pass += str.charAt(char)
  }
  return pass;
}
console.log(generateP())
```

Comment: So you want to generate passwords with EVERY type of symbol?

Comment: Take one random upper case letter, one random lower case letter, one random digit, one random symbol and 12 random characters from all groups. Shuffle them.

Comment: This script work well but it sometimes generates password without numbers

Comment: I need to solve it

Comment: This will help: [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take one random upper case letter, one random lower case letter, one random digit, one random symbol and 12 random characters from all groups. Shuffle them (I've copied the shuffle function from [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array))

```js
function getRandomChar(str) {
  return str.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length));
}

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (currentIndex != 0) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
      array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
  }

  return array;
}

function generateP(options) {
  const groups = options?.groups ?? [
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    '1234567890',
    '!@#$%^&()_+~`|}{[]:;?><,./-='
  ];
  const length = options?.length ?? 16;
  let pass = groups.map(getRandomChar).join('');
  
  const str = groups.join('');
  
  for (let i = pass.length; i <= length; i++) {
    pass += getRandomChar(str)
  }
  return shuffle(pass);
}

console.log(generateP());

// Tests
console.log('Running tests...');
for (let i = 0; i < 1e5; ++i) {
  const pass = generateP();
  if (!/[A-Z]/.test(pass) || !/[a-z]/.test(pass) || !/[0-9]/.test(pass) || !/[!@#$%^&()_+~`|}{[\]:;?><,./-=]/.test(pass)) {
    console.log('generateP() failed with: ' + pass);
  }
}
console.log('Tests finished');
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below match with your requirements:

```js
var fpwd = "";
var lpwd = 16;

for (;;) {
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 128);
    if (rnd >= 33 && rnd <= 126) {
        fpwd += String.fromCharCode(rnd);
    }
    if (fpwd.length == lpwd) {
        if (fpwd.match(/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])((?=.*\W)|(?=.*_))^[^ ]+$/g)) {
        break;
        } else {
           fpwd = "";
        }
    }
}

console.log(fpwd);
```